# How to resolve firefox issues in selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

This is my code:

```
package testpk;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Testing9 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yYDOja8n_k");
    }
}
```

I'm getting error like this:

```
at org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at testpk.Testing9.main(Testing9.java:9)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you even google parts of the error?

Answer (score 2):

You only added a partial error. It is missing the actual error, you only show the start of the stack trace.

But `org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.lock` most often means that another program is already using that socket number, or an older session is running in the background. Computers only have a limited number of network sockets/ports available, they can also be used only once at a time.

Here are some tips to resolve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992986/unable-to-bind-to-locking-port-7054-within-45000-ms-webdriver-firefox

Probably restarting your system will also help, as it will free up the socket currently in use.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all tmp files and restarting system may help.
Check below links
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4790

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/7WFcvt70BUw

Hope this helps you.